# codeanywhere.com Python doesn't see virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I use codeanywhere.com try to create application with Python werkzeug and jinja2.
I install those library utilize virtualenv. Now I face the problem 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 4, in 
    from werkzeug import Request
    ImportError: No module named 'werkzeug'

virtualenv activated but nothing is works.
Does anybody has experience with codeanywhere.com?

Comment: I've tried to use codeanywhere but honestly can't stand it. Anyway, we're going to need the full traceback (formatted as a code block).

Answer (score 0):

Oh I solve this problem. In the container config file add instruction "source venv3/bin/activate" as shown on a picture add path to python as well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg9B0.png)